# While React native app implement in webpack error in firebase

Tags: react-native, webpack

nativeModule.js:227 Uncaught Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app().

Ensure you have:

1. imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file.
2. Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the RN 'getPackages()' method list.

Comment: I see you have not linked the android dependency correctly. In recent versions of React native auto-linking works but you have not provided details on the versions of your react-native, rn-firebase, etc. Also please post more code and not just the error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.